# Do you have to be rooted to run Ubuntu on the Nexus 4?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Nexus 4 and I want to flash Ubuntu onto it. Do I have to be rooted to do this? And is Ubuntu stable for phones?

Answer (score 0):

You do have to have the device unlocked. More information can be found on the wiki:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install?action=show&redirect=TouchInstallProcess

Comment: Ok but is it already unlocked if I ordered it straight from google play or do i have to unlock it myself?

Comment: My guess is yes based on this: https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=nexus_4_8gb&feature=ha-text-sem_bk-n4&utm_source=ha&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=sem_bk&utm_content=n4